# flutter: how to show different notifications content based on chosen topic using firebase functions in my node.js

Tags: node.js, flutter, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

in my app the user gets to choose the language of the app based on a specific button that holds the string of the language name. i wanna send notifications to them according to the language they chose to operate the app with. how do i do that with cloud functions if i subscribe the user to a different language topic based on their choice of language?

heres my current index.js code for firebase functions that subscribes to only one topic which is sending notifications in english only:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 
var newData;
 
exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messagesId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
newData = snapshot.data();
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: newData.message,
        body: newData.body,
    },
        data: {
      
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      message: newData.message,
    }

};
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic('messages', payload);

});
```

Comment: did you use subscribeToTopic when the user chooses a language?

Comment: hi karen, yes i only subscribed to the messages collection.. how do i write multiple topics(languages) inside the index.js so whichever topic the user chooses based on the button gets triggered?

Comment: in my initState currently its like this >>>> fcm.subscribeToTopic('messages');